# Ionic CORS issue in google chrome

Tags: javascript, cors

I am trying to hit URL from browser through Ionic application and getting a CORS issue , the error is:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load `http://school_mit.schnotify.com/api/v1/`. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin '`http://192.168.2.10:8100`' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://www.\[website\].com/](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35553500/xmlhttprequest-cannot-load-https-www-website-com)

Comment: you should first search on google or here before asking a question that has already thousands of answers

Comment: I searched a lot but did not get the solution

Comment: you should send allow-origin with header

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I had the same problem, I just fixed using [this Chrome Plugin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi)
It allows adds `Allow-Control-Allow-Origin: *` to the header so you can make Ajax request from any source.

In Chrome you can also [use flags](http://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/run-chromium-with-flags)

> chrome --disable-web-security

or

> --allow-file-access-from-files --allow-file-

But I prefer to use the extension because you can turn it on just when you needed  without changing your server settings.

Comment: Please always explain your suggested fix. Why does this plugin work and what does it do?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `http://192.168.2.10` as an allowed origin in your backend. Or you could use a proxy.

Answer (score 0):

CORS has to be enabled in the server side. Ionic applications work on Rest API. If you have a PHP back end you can use a framework like Slim and add these headers in your php file.

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization");
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, x-xsrf-token');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With");
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'OPTIONS') {
    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_METHOD']))
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS");
    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']))
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: {$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']}");
        exit(0);
}

/*Resr of server file*/

?>
```

These headers in the server side should solve most of the CORS problem. You can implement the same in other languages